# Resetting a game logic

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to Javascript and trying to implement a reset function.
It is a number guesser game and after I guess the correct number, I want to reset my game by pressing the reset button and would start a new game.

```
var actualNum = randomNumber();

function randomNumber(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
}

function findCorrectGuess(actualNum,userGuess){
  if(userGuess > actualNum){
    return "That is too high!"
  } else if (userGuess < actualNum){
    return "That is too low!"
  } else if (userGuess === actualNum){
    return "BOOM!"
  }
}

function reset(){
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
  el = document.getElementById('player-guess')
  el.removeChild(el.firstChild)
}

function clearField(){
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
}

function guessToUI(){
  let userGuess = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('player-guess').innerHTML = `<center><h1>Your last guess was</h1><h2>${userGuess}</h2><h3>${findCorrectGuess(parseInt(actualNum),parseInt(userGuess))}</h3></center>`
}

function listeners(){
  document.getElementById('guesser').addEventListener('click', guessToUI);
  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clearField);
  document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
}

listeners();
```

After I guess the right number and click the reset button, it seems as if the previous number that was generated by my randomNumber function still persists onto the new game. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that generates your random number into the reset method so that you get a new random number.

```
function reset(){
  actualNum = randomNumber();
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
  el = document.getElementById('player-guess')
  el.removeChild(el.firstChild)
}
```